# Android Upload a file to dropbox using APIv2

Tags: android

I am trying to upload a csv file to Dropbox using the new APIv2, but it doesnt work properly. I am using two Buttons. First Button have the OnClick method "dropbox" for the authentication and its work fine. But the second OnClick method "upload" doesnt work. I am not sure about "config" and what the parameters are. Need your help. Here is the code.

```
public void dropbox(View view) {
        Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(MainActivity.this, APP_KEY);

    }
```

---

```js
 public void uploadfile(View view){
         DbxClientV2 client;
        DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder("examples-v2-demo")
                .withHttpRequestor(new OkHttp3Requestor(OkHttp3Requestor.defaultOkHttpClient()))
                .build();

        client = new DbxClientV2(requestConfig, ACCESS_TOKEN);

        try  {
            File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "u1u2u.csv");
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            FileMetadata metadata = client.files().uploadBuilder("/u1u2u.csv")
                    .uploadAndFinish(in);
        }
        catch(DbxException | IOException e){

        }

    }
```

I was trying this code, from the dropbox documentation on Github, but when i run this it shows me 2 errors.

Error:(1503, 93) error: cannot access OkHttpClient
class file for okhttp3.OkHttpClient not found
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: what is the error? Can you post the log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to add the dependency for OkHttp.

```
StandardHttpRequestor requestor = new StandardHttpRequestor(config);
DbxRequestConfig requestConfig = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder(clientUserAgentId)
    .withHttpRequestor(requestor)
    .build();
new DbxClientV2(requestConfig, auth.getAccessToken(), auth.getHost());
```

Comment: Thanks. The errors dont occur anymore, but i still cant upload files.

Comment: CloudRail offer a good and easy way for Dropbox, Box, Google Drive (and so on) implementation https://cloudrail.com/integrations/interfaces/CloudStorage